# how reminder to specific day ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a calendar that i'm trying set a reminder to a specific day.
This day i set in a form but i don't know how to set reminder for a day on calendar.

```
   {calendar.map((week, index) => 
          <div key={index} className="week">
            {week.map((day, index) => 
            <>
              <div key={index} className="day " onClick={() => !beforeToday(day) && setValue(day) || setIsOpenModal(true)}>
                <div className={dayStyles(day, value)}>
                  {day.format('D').toString()}
                  <div className='reminder'>
                    {formData.map(item => getDay === item.Date ? (
                      <>
                      <p>{item.Reminder}</p>
                      <p>{item.Date}</p>
                      <p>{item.Time}</p>
                      <p>{item.City}</p>
                    </>
                    ) : (
                        ''
                    ))}
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>  
            </>
            )}
          </div>
        )}
```

Comment: What is `helperCalendar`? A two-dimensional array of `Date`s?

Comment: Yes it is a two-dimensional array

Comment: You are going to need to compare the current `day` to the form values somehow. Please clarify how the reminder day is stored. Also, do not post code in the comments. Edit your question and add it in there.

Comment: I tryed do that, i get the date of day clicked and compare with the date that i get by form, but when i display, shows "buy milk" for every day, not just to a specific day

Comment: Your current code shows "buy milk" for every day, but I'm not seeing any attempt to compare the mapped day to the form day.

Comment: i made this verification, but forgot to put on code.
is if the date are the same as i have from form show "buy milk"
if not, just show nothing

Comment: Ok, so [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71833400/edit) your question and add the code

Comment: Done, "formData" is the state the i receive the form data

Comment: So it's an array...? And what is `getDay`? Are you using a DatePicker in your form? Is the formData day also a `Date`? Or is it like a month string "4" and a date string "11" or something? Sorry but this is really trivial stuff and you are not providing enough info to solve it.

Comment: getDay is a value that i get from click and format date
yes i am using a DatePicker on form, yes formData has a Date with the same format by getDay. 

Also thank you for help

Comment: You need something like `item.date.getMonth() === day.getMonth() && item.date.getDate() === day.getDate()`